# socket.recvfrom() works with one type of UDP stream, but not the other

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, recvfrom

I know there are a couple of questions out there that already discuss the issue of the `recvfrom` function hanging, however, I haven't been able to find a question/response that has led me to a solution.

#### My setup (kind of hacky)

In my setup I have a Windows 10 machine running a ubuntu 16.04 VM (using VmWare Workstation 12 as the hosting program).

- Windows IP: 192.168.0.100
- Ubuntu IP: 192.168.0.102

The hacky part of my set up is in the way I'm sending udp packets from my host machine to my VM. I have a couple of `.pcap` files of captured UDP packets that I am injecting back into the network with a program called [PlayCap](http://www.signal11.us/oss/playcap/). With this setup, I can verify that the replayed packets are indeed being injected correctly to my VM network via wireshark.

#### PCAP file info

For my testing, I've been using two different `.pcap` files that contain UDP packets from two completely different streams, however, the source (192.168.0.100) and destination(192.168.0.102) IP addresses are the same. They also have the same destination port(5000).

This may or may not be necessary to explain, but the format of the payloads of these UDP packets are very different. One has a payload who's bytes represent a serialized XML document. The other payload is just a byte array representing different values of sensor measurements in different locations in the array, etc.

If you're wondering why I'm explaining the payloads of these UDP messages, read on.

#### The Problem

So the problem that my program is facing is that it can successfully receive packets from one replayed UDP stream, but not the other. The one that works is the stream with the XML payload. The one that doesn't work and causes the `recvfrom` function to hang and wait for data is the sensor data payload.

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "192.168.0.102"
UDP_PORT = 5000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:

    buffer_size = 2048
    print "1"
    data, address  = sock.recvfrom(buffer_size)
    print "2"
    print "received message:", data
```

Output using XML payload Packets

```
>>> 1
>>> a bunch of xml
>>> 2
>>> 1
>>> a bunch of xml
....
```

Goes on until the PlayCap is done playing the `.pcap` file

Output using Sensor Data Packets

```
>>> 1
>>>
```

Program hangs on the `recvfrom` function.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or can provide any information as to why this would happen? I've looked at the [socket API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) and all the other questions involving `recvfrom` and `socket`.

#### Update

After digging deeper and comparing the headers of the two packets, I found that there was a difference in the source/destination mac addresses. This makes sense since the `.pcap` with the sensor data was captured on another persons computer, and the xml data was captured on my machine. So I think my program wasn't picking up the sensor data because the sensor data was getting sent to the correct IP but not the correct Mac address. I verified this by plugging in the sensor board directly into my network. The UDP packets containing the sensor data immediately were picked up by my program.

Comment: Perhaps the packets in the not-working stream have incorrect checksums?

Comment: "_Is there a tool out there that can change the source/destination mac addresses of the replayed .pcap to simulate real data flow?_" The answer to that is yes, but "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"